# Does this let us distribute the app to my app users?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/

Does this let us distribute the app to my app users?
Can we push updates easily?
Are there any limitations?

Please help me for these upper listed questions.

Comment: What is a “BH user”?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it. Generate ipa using following link.

http://johannesluderschmidt.de/provision-ios-ipa-app-for-in-house-enterprise-distribution/2993/

Host it on dropbox and share the link with your users.

http://dr-palaniraja.blogspot.com/2011/06/distribute-your-iphoneipad-adhoc-builds.html